# Change query to sum or aggregate data

Tags: sql, sum, having

I have a SQL query that is working fine, but I now need to change it up to sum up the data and I'm not sure how to go about it -

```
SELECT store, tintermodel, tinterserial, eventdetails, trunc(datetime), COUNT(*)
FROM tinter_events
WHERE tintermodel = 'FM 8000DE'  
AND (datetime >= to_timestamp('2017-05-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
AND datetime < to_timestamp('2017-08-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
AND function = 'Set Colorant Level'
AND eventdetails IN ('R3[128]', 'G2[128]', 'W1[345]', 'Y3[512]', 'N1[185]', 
'R4[128]', 'L1[128]', 'B1[550]', 'B1[512]', 'Y1[128]', 'R2[185]')
GROUP BY store, tintermodel, tinterserial, eventdetails, trunc(datetime) 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY store, tinterserial, eventdetails, trunc(datetime);
```

What this does is gives me a count of any date a specific model (by serial number) is filled ("set colorant level") more than once in a day.  This gives me a display for each date this happens.

But now I need to sum it up by store for each colorant total (aka SUBSTR(eventdetails,1,2)).  In other words, have a list of the stores on the left and a column for each colorant with just a total of number of **days** that each colorant was filled more than once.

I'm not sure how to handle that since I've already got a count going to give me only occurrences where a colorant was filled more than once a day on a specific model/serial.  Some sort of SUM/SUMIF perhaps?  Or a sub-select?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: To be honest - do not know the database I am using.  Just using SQL Developer that has been set up for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the basic data as:

```
SELECT store, SUBSTR(eventdetails, 1, 2) as colorant, COUNT(*) as numdays
FROM (SELECT store, tintermodel, tinterserial, eventdetails, trunc(datetime), COUNT(*)
      FROM tinter_events
      WHERE tintermodel = 'FM 8000DE' AND 
            datetime >= to_timestamp('2017-05-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND
            datetime < to_timestamp('2017-08-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND
            function = 'Set Colorant Level' AND
            eventdetails IN ('R3[128]', 'G2[128]', 'W1[345]', 'Y3[512]', 'N1[185]', 
'R4[128]', 'L1[128]', 'B1[550]', 'B1[512]', 'Y1[128]', 'R2[185]')
      GROUP BY store, tintermodel, tinterserial, eventdetails, trunc(datetime) 
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
     ) t
GROUP BY store, SUBSTR(eventdetails, 1, 2);
```

This produces the data you want, but in three columns.  You can use conditional aggregation to pivot it:

```
SELECT store,
       SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTR(eventdetails, 1, 2) = 'R3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as R3,
       SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTR(eventdetails, 1, 2) = 'G2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as G2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN SUBSTR(eventdetails, 1, 2) = 'W1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as W1,
       . . .
FROM (SELECT store, tintermodel, tinterserial, eventdetails, trunc(datetime), COUNT(*)
      FROM tinter_events
      WHERE tintermodel = 'FM 8000DE' AND 
            datetime >= to_timestamp('2017-05-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND
            datetime < to_timestamp('2017-08-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND
            function = 'Set Colorant Level' AND
            eventdetails IN ('R3[128]', 'G2[128]', 'W1[345]', 'Y3[512]', 'N1[185]', 
'R4[128]', 'L1[128]', 'B1[550]', 'B1[512]', 'Y1[128]', 'R2[185]')
      GROUP BY store, tintermodel, tinterserial, eventdetails, trunc(datetime) 
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
     ) t
GROUP BY store;
```